# Show that $\prod _{_{r=1}}^{\infty }\left[1+\frac{x}{r}\right]e^{-x/r}$ converges for all finite x (except for the zeros of 1+x/r)

Tags: sequences-and-series

Background: This is Arfken et all Mathematical methods 12.5.8

There is a hint to write the nth factor as $1+a_n$

An infinite product $\prod^\infty(1+a_n)$ [diverges or converges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product#Convergence_criteria) with $\sum (a_n)$. Therefore the first term will diverge by comparison with the harmonic, and the second term will converge but I don't know how to proceed with the combined product. 
Also, what is meant by the zeros of 1+x/r?

Comment: Actually, both $\prod\left(1+\frac{x}r\right)$ and $\prod e^{-x/r}$ diverge... But what can you say about the behaviour of $a_r$ defined by the identity $$1+a_r=\left(1+\frac{x}r\right)e^{-x/r}$$ when $r\to\infty$?

Comment: @D what about when $x\ge0$ then it will be $\frac{1}{e^{\infty}}=0$. Thus it conditionally converges (not in the tradition mathematical sense |f(x)|. I think this question may be wrong though.

Comment: Please be aware that if the partial products $\prod\limits_{k=1}^nx_k$ converge to zero then the infinite product $\prod\limits_{n=1}^\infty x_n$ is said to be divergent, hence indeed $\prod e^{-x/r}$ diverges *for every $x$*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $r>|x|$ take logarithms
$$\ln\left[\left(1+\frac xr\right)e^{-x/r}\right]
=-\frac xr+\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{x^n}{nr^n}=-\frac{x^2}{2r^2}
+O((x/r)^3).$$
This means that the sum of $\ln\left[\left(1+\frac xr\right)e^{-x/r}\right]$ over all these $r$ is bounded by a multiple of the convergent
series $\sum1/r^2$, so it converges.

Comment: Eventually r will be greater than any x so this is always works. Do you have any ideas about what the zeros are of 1+x/r?

Comment: Well $1+x/r=0$ iff $x/r=-1$ iff $x=$ what?

Comment: I don't think that's what they meant. I don't think zero is a divergent product. It's not important that important. Possibly just an error in the text.

Comment: I'm confused again. That $x/r$ is actually $-\sum_{r>x}^\infty(\frac{x}{r})$ which = constant*harmonic which diverges.

Comment: Now I'm confused: $x/r$ is just $x/r$. The product is zero when $x$ is a negative integer (but still counts as a convergent infinite product nonetheless).

Comment: If x is negative, the first term now converges by alternating series test and the second term diverges with $e^{\infty}$ and the same predicament occurs

Comment: I see no "predicament". Both the products $\prod (1+x/r)$ and $\prod e^{-x/r}$ diverge, but that is of no consequence as the product $\prod(1+x/r)e^{-x/r}$ converges.

Comment: Ok, I see, even as negative it isn't alternating, I think you proved that it diverges. You have $\ln(\prod_{r>x}^\infty e^{-x/r})=-\sum_{r>x}^\infty\frac{x}{r}=constant*\sum\frac{1}{n}$ -which diverges. I'll have to come back to this problem later. Maybe it will come to me when I've finished more problems.

Answer (score -1):

Stealing the credit off of Lord Shark's answer and putting it in a form that I understand: Instead of taking the ln just expand the exponential into it's series and multiply the product out into a sum:

$$\prod _{_{n=1}}^{\infty }\left[1+\frac{x}{n}\right]e^{-x/n}=(1+\color{red}{\sum_n \frac{x}{n}}+\sum \frac{x^2}{n_1 n_2}\dots)(1-\color{red}{\sum\frac{x}{n}}+\sum\frac{x^2}{2!n^2}\dots)$$
The red terms in the product cross multiply with 1 and sum to zero, so we get a sum of convergent sums: $$(1+\sum\frac{x^2}{2!n^2}+\sum \frac{x^2}{n_1 n_2}\dots)$$ with each of these sums and higher orders converging with comparison to $\sum\frac{1}{n^2}$ so the final answer that they converge was correct.

Comment: Not a proof unless the $\cdots$ terms are suitably estimated or at least controlled.